# How to Restart PyQt4 Application

Tags: python, pyqt4, application-restart

Is there a way to restart PyQt application `QApplication`

I have an app created with pyqt4 and python 2.6 using below code

`app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)`

i have settings options where i set some settings. Now when i save settings i need to reload the application so that new settings are effected. Without the need of end user to exit and launch the app again.

Comment: Personally I'd just write it so that it could reload the settings without needing a restart. But doing it this way: In your `__main__`, make it so that it catches the exit reason of the program. If it's `RESTART` (Or something like that), relaunch the app (This is in a loop obv), else quit?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and simply used this at the appropriate place:

```
subprocess.Popen([__file__])
sys.exit(0)
```

It was a simple application, and didn't need any further arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I explain how I did it :

I create a extra one file main.py which calls my actual main program file dash.py.
And I emits a signal for restarting (my programs auto updates at the closeEvent) so I required to emit a signal for it. This is the snippets hope this will help you.

This one is in my main program file in dash.py

```
def restart(self):
    # create a signal equivalent to "void someSignal(int, QWidget)"
    self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("RESTARTREQUIRED"), True)
```

This one in main.py which calls actual program only and restarts the app

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
from bin import dash

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    uDesk = dash.app()
    uDesk.show()
    uDesk.actionRestart.triggered.disconnect()
    # define restart slot
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def restartSlot():
        print 'Restarting app'
        global uDesk
        uDesk.deleteLater()
        uDesk = dash.app()
        uDesk.show()
        uDesk.actionRestart.triggered.disconnect()   
        uDesk.actionRestart.triggered.connect(restartSlot)
        print 'New app started !'

    QtCore.QObject.connect(uDesk,
                   QtCore.SIGNAL("RESTARTREQUIRED"),
                   restartSlot)
    uDesk.actionRestart.triggered.connect(restartSlot)
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Hope this was helpful !!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Changing the way to get the application path

You could just start a new process and exit yours, something like this: (CODE NOT TESTED, but based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129788/how-to-restart-my-own-qt-application#5129898))

```
// Restart Application
def restart(self, abort):
    // Spawn a new instance of myApplication:
    proc = QProcess()
    //proc.start(self.applicationFilePath());
    import os
    proc.start(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    self.exit(0);
```

Code it as a method of your Qapplication or even a function if you don't feel like subclassing

Comment: This won't work since, with PyQt, QApplication.applicationFilePath() returns the path to python interpreter.

Comment: @Jeannot Oh I didn't know that, I edited the code so that it uses the `os` module

Comment: @Fabio Diniz, I made my application as a single instance app. So i cant launch another instance of the same app. I think i cant use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I restart TicTacToe game in **PySide** (it should be the same in **PyQt**):

I have a single class - a `QWidget` class - in which is coded the **Tic Tac Toe** game. To restart the application I use:

1. `import subprocess`
2. a `QPushButton()` like so:

   `self.button = QPushButton("Restart", self)`
3. the connection of the `button` to `Slot`:

   `self.buton.clicked.connect(self.restartGame)`
4. the `Slot` for this button, like so:

   `def restartGame(self):
       self.close()
       subprocess.call("python" + " TicTAcToe.py", shell=True)`

All these are in the same - single - class. And what these do: close the active window of the game and create a new one.

How this code looks in the TicTacToe class:

```
import subprocess
class TicTacToe(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.button = QPushButton("Restart", self)
        self.buton.clicked.connect(self.restartGame)
    def restartGame(self):
        self.close()
        subprocess.call("python" + " TicTacToe.py", shell=True)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = TicTacToe()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**EDIT**

I know this doesn't answer the question (it doesn't restart a `QApplication`), but I hope this helps those who want to restart their `QWidget` single class.