# How to restart an QApplication

Tags: python, pyqt, restart, qapplication

I need to restart my application when a button is clicked, but I'm having some problems with it. I've tried two methods:

1. Tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372164/how-do-i-restart-my-pyqt-application) and it indeed restarts the application, but I get a `Gtk_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)` error for every widget, and all of them look different in the restarted application, with a very "old" look (similar to TkInter widgets). Is there a way so solve this error? Besides this, the application works fine.
2. I also tried:

   ```
   subprocess.Popen("/home/pi/pywork/pyqt/of2.py")
   sys.exit(0)
   ```

   [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221361/how-to-restart-pyqt4-application), but I get the following error: `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`. Is there a way to override this denied permission?

None of them seem to work properly. Is there a way to fix any of them? Do you know an alternative method to restart the application?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "restart", because the two examples you give are very different. Do you actually need to create a completely *new* process? Or do you just need to create a new application object and main window within the *current* process? Or perhaps all you need to do is to create a new main window, but using the same application object? What actual problem are you trying solve?

Comment: I want to close the current process and start a new one. I solved the widget errors on the first suggestion by setting a style on the app, so by placing `setStyle("GTK+")`, the widget errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [QProcess.startDetached](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1):

```
QProcess.startDetached("/home/pi/pywork/pyqt/of2.py")
sys.exit(0)
```

You also have to properly add the [shebang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script) to your python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Answer (score 1):

The second method gives an error because the file is not executable. You could fix that, but it is probably more robust to just re-run the script using the same python executable. It would also be a good idea to avoid hard-coding the script path.

Here is a simple demo script that implements all that:

```
import sys, os, subprocess
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

FILEPATH = os.path.abspath(__file__)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton(
            'Restart [PID: %d]' % QtGui.qApp.applicationPid(), self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        try:
            subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, FILEPATH])
        except OSError as exception:
            print('ERROR: could not restart aplication:')
            print('  %s' % str(exception))
        else:
            QtGui.qApp.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 400, 100, 50)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```