# How do I reset a TraitsUI python application?

Tags: python, pyqt4, traitsui

I am working on a Python program which performs various calculations. There are many different parameters that need to be inputed, and it can get confusing to remember what changes you made to the different inputs. I want to have a button that resets everything to their default values, so basically like restarting it, but without actually closing it/needing to run it again. I have used TraitsUI to design the GUI. How can I implement this ? I saw on the TraitsUI User manual that there is a reset command:

```
    reset(destroy=True)
    "Resets the contents of a user interface"
```

,but I don't actually know how and where to use this.

Here is a quick overview of how my code is formatted from start to end.

```
    import os
    os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
    os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt'
    from traits.api import HasTraits, Range, ...
    ...
    class class1(HasTraits)
    ...
    class class10(HasTraits)
    mrm = class10()
    mrm.configure_traits(kind='livemodal')
```

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372164/how-do-i-restart-my-pyqt-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106058/how-to-restart-an-qapplication) but they either didn't work or I just don't know to implement them properly in my program's layout. Looking forward to any advice/help.

Answer (score 0):

I just read into this but look into `reset_traits()`

Try adding a "refresh" button to the GUI where

```
def _refresh_fired(self):
    self.reset_traits()
```

This will reset all traits within your class. If you want to reset some of the traits, pass a list of strings along with it.

```
self.reset_traits(['trait1', 'trait2'])
```