# QNetworkAccessManager `get` method crashes on restart

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

I am currently adding a functionality to my app that would allow it to restart.

This is what the main looks like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int RESTART_CODE = 1000;
    int return_from_event_loop_code;
    QPointer<QApplication> app;
    QPointer<foo> main_window;
    do
    {
        if(main_window)
            delete main_window; 
        if(app) 
            delete app;

            app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
            main_window = new foo();
            main_window->show();
            app->setActiveWindow(main_window);

            return_from_event_loop_code = app->exec();
    } 
    while(return_from_event_loop_code==RESTART_CODE);

  return return_from_event_loop_code;
}
```

Now the first time runs fine however when the application is restarted using the `RestartApp` method mentioned below . The get method of `QNetworkAccessManager` returns the lock error. This is what my code looks like

```
void foo::MethodA()
{
    ....
    ....
    QUrl url("some url");
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(url);
    networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QObject::connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)),static_cast<Qt::ConnectionType>(Qt::QueuedConnection | Qt::UniqueConnection));
    currentReply = networkManager->get(request); //Crashes when the app is restarted again
    connect(currentReply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),this, SLOT(slotNetworkError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),Qt::UniqueConnection);
}

//Slot
void foo::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* rply)
{
    ....
    .....
    rply->deleteLater();
}

//Slot
void foo::RestartApp()
{
    QCoreApplication::exit(1000);
}
```

Now here is what happens when the app starts for the first time everything is fine. However when the RestartApp method is called and `return_from_event_loop_code = app->exec();` method in main is called again this time at the statement `currentReply = networkManager->get(request);` in MethodA the app crashes and ends up in

```
mlock.c

void __cdecl _unlock (
        int locknum
        )
{
        /*
         * leave the critical section.
         */
        LeaveCriticalSection( _locktable[locknum].lock );
}
```

Any idea on why the app crashes on the get statement of QNetworkAccessManager when the app is given the instruction to restart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some investigation on the crash. It's indeed caused by destruction of `QApplication`. `QNetworkAccessManager` internally uses a `QNetworkConfigurationManagerPrivate` object. This object is created when needed and used until the application finishes. The `qNetworkConfigurationManagerPrivate` function is used to create or get existing object.

When `QApplication` is destroyed, it executes all post routines, including `connManager_cleanup`. This function indirectly destroys `QNetworkConfigurationManagerPrivate` object and sets `appShutdown` local flag. When this flag is set, `qNetworkConfigurationManagerPrivate` function will not create new `QNetworkConfigurationManagerPrivate` objects anymore. So after destruction of `QApplication` `QNetworkAccessManager` becomes non-functional.

I thought it's a misuse of `QApplication` object, but recently I found a proof link that the use is correct.

Qt's [Coding Conventions](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Coding-Conventions) state:

> Q[Core]Application is a singleton class. There can only be one instance at a time. However, that instance can be destroyed and a new one can be created.

So this issue should be considered a Qt bug.

Comment: Is this wrong ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129788/how-to-restart-my-own-qt-application

Comment: Yes, I think that answers that advise recreating `QApplication` are not correct (they are not accepted though, and the most high rated answer seems to be correct). I've added more details to my answer.