# How to reboot PyQt5 application

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

I'm trying to restart my application after an update from the client side. I was able to achieve till the auto update part. I tried to surf on **How to restart PyQt application?**. There are few similar questions earlier, but none of them have good explanation or example with a button click event. Could you guys help me understand on how to reboot a PyQt application. Basically I want to restart the application from `if __name__ == '__main__':` everytime there is an update.

Note: `AppLogin` is my private module I created to handle application login. So basically that would be the landing `QDialog` once application is opened.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import AppLogin

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        btn = QPushButton(main_window)
        btn.setText('close')
        btn.pressed.connect(self.restart)
        main_window.show()

    def restart(self):
        # Here goes the code for restart
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    appctxt = QApplication(sys.argv)
    log_in = AppLogin.Login()
    if log_in.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
        main_window = QMainWindow()
        ui = App()
        exit_code = appctxt.exec_()
        sys.exit(exit_code)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logic is to end the eventloop and launch the application an instant before it closes:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


def restart():
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()
    status = QtCore.QProcess.startDetached(sys.executable, sys.argv)
    print(status)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    print("[PID]:", QtCore.QCoreApplication.applicationPid())

    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    window.show()

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Restart")
    button.clicked.connect(restart)

    window.setCentralWidget(button)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for acknowledging, I tried the code sample. It is only stopping the application, the application is not restarting.
fyi - I'm on Windows

Comment: @testuserme How do you run your application? Do you use some IDE? try launching the script from the console

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to close (or forget) the QMainWindow and recreate it.

If you just "show()" a single widget, the same idea works fine.

```
import sys
import uuid

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    singleton: 'MainWindow' = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = QPushButton(f'RESTART\n{uuid.uuid4()}')
        btn.clicked.connect(MainWindow.restart)
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)
        self.show()

    @staticmethod
    def restart():
        MainWindow.singleton = MainWindow()


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    MainWindow.restart()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks this works!