# Loading defaults of all widgets in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, default, reset

I would like to use a button_clicked slot to reset all the widgets used in the application. I tried calling the function used in the application constructor, which is present by default when you create an ui application project in Qt.

`ui->setup(this)`.

I called the same in the `pushbutton_clicked()` slot function. For example -

```
void MyMainWindow::on_pushButtonLdDefaults_clicked()
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

This *gives me the expected result*, all the *widgets get reset*. *But* after this, *all the buttons and widgets become unresponsive*. No events are heard after this.
**Am i doing something wrong by calling `ui->setup(this)`?**

Also, If there is any other way to easily reset the widgets, please share.

Comment: The setup() function creates objects by separating memory, so you should not use that function to reset.

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks. Found another solution here to restart the whole app, which servers my purpose (kind of). [Restart_Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129788/how-to-restart-my-own-qt-application)